# Failing Unit Test In Grails 1.3.7 Spock

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I have this piece of code in a controller:

```
def update = {

    Map model = [:]
    model.foo = params.foo
    model.bar = params.bar

    def result = ""

    MyObject obj = MyObject.findWhere(bar:bar, foo:foo)

    MyObjectService.updateObj(model,obj)
    result = true

    render result as JSON
}
```

And this simple unit test:

```
def 'controller update'() {
    given:
        controller.params.foo = foo
        controller.params.bar = bar

        MyObject obj = new MyObject(bar:bar, foo:foo)
        mockDomain(MyObject,[obj])
    when:
        controller.update()
    then:
        1 * MyObject.findWhere(bar:bar, foo:foo) >> obj
        1 * MyObjectService.updateObj(model,obj)
    and:    
        def model = JSON.parse(controller.response.contentAsString)
        model == true
    where:
        foo = "0"
        bar = "1"
}
```

Now this is failing by and it is telling me that, "not static method findWhere is applicable..." for those arguments. That "MyObject" is just an orm class, and when I run that application everything seems to be working fine, but the test is failing.

My logic is this:

I want to count how many times the `findWhere` and `updateObj` methods are call and I am also mocking their response. So `findWhere` will return the object I already mocked, and pass it on to the service.

Any ideas why this is failing ?

Answer (score 1):

For mocking static methods you should use Spock's [GroovyStub](https://spock-framework.readthedocs.org/en/latest/interaction_based_testing.html#mocking-static-methods) class which introduced in v0.7.

Comment: I am usgin groovy 1.7, spock 0.5, forgot to mention that

Comment: I would honestly advise moving your dynamic method calls into a Service class and creating an integration test on your Service method. Then you can test interactions to the service methods to get around trying to mock in this way. You'll also be adhering to best practice as a bonus :)